# How to redirect to a view from a buddy class asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, authentication

This is my authorize class which overrides the default AurthorizeCore, I'd like to redirect the user to an error page if he's not authorized. How can I accomplish that?

```
public class UserAcess : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private UserRepository _userRepo = new UserRepository();

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {

        var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (isAuthorized)
        {
            var canUse = this._userRepo.CanUserUseApp(httpContext.User.Identity.Name);

            // If you can't use this app, guess what? ERROR PAGE fun times.

            if (!canUse)
            {
                isAuthorized = false;

                 //redirect the user a view that I've made here.
                return isAuthorized;

            }
        }


        var personRole = this._userRepo.getPersonRolebyAdName(httpContext.User.Identity.Name);


        //TODO Refactor this so that it checks if it's filled.

        httpContext.Session["PersonID"] = personRole.Person.PersonID;
        httpContext.Session["PersonRoleID"] = personRole.PersonRoleID;
        httpContext.Session["UserName"] = personRole.Person.UserName;
        httpContext.Session["Role"] = personRole.Role.Description;
        httpContext.Session["FirstName"] = personRole.Person.FirstName;
        httpContext.Session["LastName"] = personRole.Person.LastName;

        return isAuthorized;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this by overriding the [HandleUnauthorizedRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.handleunauthorizedrequest.aspx) method:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.Result = new ViewResult 
    { 
        ViewName = "SomeUnauthorizedViewName" 
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you again Darin! You're so helpful. How Do I actually pass a filterContext?

Comment: @Gotjosh, what `filterContext`? You simply put this method override inside your `UserAcess` class. It will be automatically called. You don't have to call or pass anything. Just ensure you have specified a proper path to an view existing view which will be rendered.